# Can you inverse conditional probabilities using De Morgan's laws (or similar)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

lets say that $P(A|B) = X$

is true. Could something along the lines of

$P(A^c|B^c) = 1 -  X$

, or maybe

$P(B^c|A^c) = X$

be said.

De Morgan's laws have been so useful and i was hoping they would extend further in probability, however i cannot find anything online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I tell you that the shaded region is 60% of the Rhombus’s area, and ask you to talk about the areas of other regions, the only region you can talk about is the other 40%.

i.e In your case $P[B\cap A^c|B] = 1-X$ is all you can infer given the information at hand.

$\qquad$

[image]